# What is "computer://" path in nautilus and how to access it as root?

Tags: nautilus

I am curious what `computer://` is, in terms of its implementation on the file system/in the nautilus executable/as a configuration provided to nautilus?

1. Perhaps it is a configurable group (of paths) for nautilus, configurable on a user basis.

The reason I ask is because it is not accessible with root's nautilus. If #1 is correct, how does one create `computer://` and/or how does one create such path groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is not correct. I mean the fact that this kind of special URI is not configurable on a user basis.

`computer://` is a [special URI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98562/37944) like is `recent://`, `trash://`, `burn://`, ao.

> The reason those URIs exist is because Nautilus uses a virtual file system called Gnome Virtual File System (gvfs) which is built on top of another virtual file system called FUSE. Specifically those URIs are configured in the `/usr/lib/gvfs/` directory named `gvfsd-*`. These are binary files so don't try and edit them. - *via [Rothgar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101079/37944)*

You can get access to these special URIs as root by using dbus:

```
gksu dbus-launch nautilus computer://
```